# How to get next time in every 30 mints PHP?

Tags: php, date

In our HR system employees should work minimum 8.30 hours. if not they have to put the reason. without filling the reason field they can't **Punch-out**.

Now we need.... even employee works 8.30 hrs restrict them to punch out till particular time.

**Ex1 : employee punch in 9.10 AM when it hits 5.40 PM he/she can punch out.
but now i want restrict them... they can't punch out till 6 PM without filling reason field**

**Ex2 : If they punch in 8.20 AM they can punch out at 4.50 PM they can punch out but i want restict them till 5 PM without filling reason field they can't**

below the code which i use now how to implement with my rules ?

```
if(date('N',strtotime($dateTime)) != "6"){
        if(!$req->note){

            if((strtotime($dateTime) - strtotime($attendance->in_time)) < 30600){
                    $time = (strtotime($dateTime) - strtotime($attendance->in_time));
                    $minutes = floor($time / 60);
                    $minute = $minutes%60;
                    $hours = floor($time / 3600);
           return new IceResponse(IceResponse::ERROR,"You have worked only ".$hours.":".$minute." Hours    You Can't Punch out without Fill the Reason");

    }}  }
```

here i have used other rules this no need on **SATURDAY**